# Popup with WMS to WFS with OpenLayers

Tags: wms, geojson, wfs, popup

I have the following code:

For the layers I used:

```
var layer_wms_lote_rural = new ol.layer.Tile({
          preload: Infinity,
          visible: true,
              source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/municipio/ows',params: {'LAYERS': 'municipio:lote_rural', 
                                                                              'TILED': true, 
                                                                              'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                                                                              'FORMAT': 'image/png8'
                                                                             },
                serverType: 'geoserver'
              })),
          name:'lote_rural' 
        }); 
        //Declara un layer vector WMS 
        var layer_wms_lote_urbano = new ol.layer.Tile({
          preload: Infinity,
          visible: true,
              source: new ol.source.TileWMS(({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/municipio/ows',params: {'LAYERS': 'municipio:lote_urbano', 
                                                                              'TILED': true, 
                                                                              'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                                                                              'FORMAT': 'image/png8'
                                                                             },
                serverType: 'geoserver'
              })),
           name:'lote_urbano'                           
        }); 

For the click over layer:

    map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        var layers = map.getLayers();
        var num_length = layers.getLength();
        var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
        var viewResolution = (vista_inicial.getResolution());

    var q=1;
    //for(var q=1;q<num_length;q++){

            var url_info = layers.item(q).getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(coordinate, viewResolution, projection_srid,{'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'});   
            var url_feature_query = layers.item(q).getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(coordinate, viewResolution, projection_srid,{'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'});   
            var newLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                                                        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                                                        url: url_feature_query
                                        }),
                                style: new ol.style.Style({
                                                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: '#00FFFF',width: 4})
                                                        }),
                                name: 'temporal'
            });

        var quanty=newLayer.getSource().getFeatures().length;
        map.addLayer(newLayer); 
        content.innerHTML = '<p>Informacion</p><code><iframe seamless="seamless" src="' + url_info + '"></iframe></code>';
        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
        map.removeLayer(vectorial);
        vectorial = newLayer;

        //}//FOR    
    });
```

but only get one layer, in this case el number "q", and want to select any layer when click on map to show popup but the "for" not works because when I count the number features of the newLayer is ZERO!!!!but in the map draw a poly.

Somebody have idea what is the problem?

I use OL3.

Comment: please add the section of your code where you add the layers to your map